# Best way to do front-end public and restricted area with October CMS?

Tags: themes, octobercms

I have to create a website with limited public access pages.

All pages have a header section with a signin / signup link and when the user is already logged in, a logout link. To do this, I must place the rainlab user plugin session component in my layout with security=all (to prevent the ajax onLogout administrator error from being detected)

But by doing this, I can no longer use this layout for restricted access pages.

So, what is the right way to do it?

I thought of using 2 layout, one to public access with security = all and one to restricted access with security=user, but I'm not really satisfied to have to use 2 layout for a difference so minimal

any smarter solution ? thanks by advance

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42552191/69537

Comment: thanks Meysam, this link do the job to explain the login workflow with a redirection into login page. My question was just if it is a good way to do a private to use 2 differents layout. It seems this is the smarter solution.

Comment: Here I specify what I am trying to do :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700066/how-to-insert-login-form-in-a-restricted-acces-page-with-good-security, Thank you for taking a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same layout for both restricted and public pages. Add the [session] component reference to the layout but don't set properties on it in the layout itself. Set the 'security' property on a per page (and not on the layout itself) basis.

So the top of your layout would look something like:

```
name="Master Layout"
description = "Master layout for almost all frontend pages."


[session]
==

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
.....
```

And the top of your pages would look like:

```
title = "Restricted Page"
url = "/classified"
layout = "master"

[session]
security = "user"
redirect = "account"
==

<div class="container">
```

I use it all the time without a problem.

Comment: thanks Pratyush, nice tip, so you have to put [session] security="all on all your public acces page ?

Comment: I usually go for "blacklisting". So I don't set any 'security' property for the Session component on public pages but explicitly set it to 'user' for pages I want to restrict to logged in users.

Comment: Also, it'd be great if you could accept my answer if you think this is indeed the right way to deal with this. Others might be looking for this too \m/

Comment: i don't know why, i did as you say but the redirect doesn't work :-( i have something like `redirect="/dashboard/account"` but the effective redirection goes to the home page

Comment: You wanna make sure that redirects are not getting chained. For example: make sure the redirection rule set on `/dashboard/account`is not the cause here

Comment: i will try to see that when i have some time, thanks