# how to insert login form in a restricted acces page with good security?

Tags: octobercms

i have to do the following stuff :

My website have some restricted pages. Instead of redirecting the user to the login page, I would like the restricted access pages themselves displays the login form. I want this behaviour because i want the user have the information he is on his expected page and he have to login first.

To do this, I have 2 layout: one for public pages and one for restricted acces page. Seems to be the best way to do.

In both of them. I need to have the session component because I have a logout link to execute ajax onlogout from plugin rainlab.user(obviously i have the `{% framework %}` tag on both)

So, the "public" page layout have component session with `security=all` and the "restricted" page layout have component session with `security=user` but no redirection (option -none- in the backend CMS component redirect list ) and the following code

```
[session]
security = "user"
==
....
{% if not user %}
   <p>you have to login first to access this page</p>
   {% partial '/account/signin' %}
{% else %}
   {% page %}
{% endif %}
....
```

with this configuration, when i try to access the restricted page, i have a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

BUT If i put `security=all`, this works like a charm but i'm a bit afraid to do weird thing here especially about security.

so my question: is a good thing to want to proceed like this and if not, what can i do to have an equivalent behaviour

(i tought about displaying the expected information on the login page where user is redirect but have no idea how to do, the intented url in session is always affected, even user click more link since he tried to access restricted page)

thanks !

Comment: I think you should set a redirect for the security=user page if you only want to show that content to logged-in users. And redirect them to a sign-up/login page. Or at least redirect them to an error page saying that they need to sign up/login before they can see the page. The first option is more user-friendly.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll follow your advice. However, the behaviour. However, the behavior I describe is very similar: instead of a redirect, the user remains on the expected page also has information like how it is on the page he wants instead of going on another pag, which can a little disturb him

Comment: Then there is no need to restrict that page to a logged-in user. Showing the login/signup using the code you showed to identify a guest is sufficient

Comment: The most common approach to implement this behavior is to save the original url (the user wanted to access) somehow. This might be in the ``SESSION`` or in a ``$_GET`` parameter. I assume you are using the User plugin, so you would have to redirect to ``example.org/user/signin?redirect=some/page``. The Account component will automatically pick up this url as redirect parameter: https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin/blob/master/components/Account.php#L173